# Como faço uma condição lógica comparando linhas de um de arquivo texto, usando o fopen em php?

Tags: php, pdo

Tenho o código abaixo onde ele abre o arquivo `material1.txt`, lê até o final e preciso fazer uma comparação de uma linha com outra por exemplo:

```
$material = fopen("c:/inetpub/wwwroot/material1.txt","r");

while(!feof($material)){
    $linha = fgets($material,4096);

    echo $linha;
}

fclose($material);
```

No arquivo tenho linhas que os campos são delimitados por "|"

**Exemplo:**

```
 material | nivel | quantidade | tipo    |
 lápis    |   1   |      20    | escolar |
 mochila  |   2   |      2     | escolar |
```

A comparação seria no nível se o valor da próxima linha for > que a anterior o nível é filho se a próxima linha o valor e < ele é pai de outro nível se valor é igual é o mesmo nível.

o que gostaria de fazer uma outra coluna onde o nível filho vai receber a coluna material do nível pai por exemplo:

| material_pai | material | nível | quantidade |
|   lápis      |  lápis   |   1   |     20     |
|   lápis      |  mochila |   2   |      2     |
|   lápis      |  caderno |   2   |      5     |
|   estojo     |  estojo  |   1   |      3     |
|   estojo     | borracha |   2   |     10     |
|  borracha    | caneta   |   3   |     20     |
|  estojo      | pincel   |   2   |     10     |

Comment: Faz um explode da linha utilizando o delimitador `|` e varre os valores utilizando i indice do array resultado.

Comment: +1 essa complexidade exercita nosso cérebro

Answer (score 0):

De forma geral sua pergunta esta confusa, compara e joga aonde, existe um buraco de lógica, quando chego na última linha comparo com quem?, não era mais fácil agrupar todos os niveis e depois comparar?

De qualquer forma acho que para esse seu caso, é melhor usar a função [file](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file.php) do PHP, por que ele irá tratar seu arquivo como uma grande matriz, sendo cada linha uma posição, então assim você iria conseguir percorrer para frente e para trás. Um exemplo bem simples que posso te dar é esse abaixo, como disse é estranha essa lógica sua.

**Exemplo #1** *(tentato seguir sua lógica)*

```
<?php
// Abre o arquivo e trasforma cada linha uma posição de uma matriz
$materiais = file("material1.txt");

// Percore todas as linhas do arquivo (ignorando a primeira linha)
// E agrupa todo mundo nos respectivos niveis
$grupos = array();  // Variavel vazia para montar os niveis
for ($l = 1; $l < count($materiais); $l++) {
 list($material, $nivel, $quantidade, $tipo) = explode("|", $materiais[$l]);

 // FIX: Verifica se existe proxima linha
 if (isset($materiais[($l + 1)])) {
  list($material2, $nivel2, $quantidade2, $tipo2) = explode("|", $materiais[($l + 1)]); // Lê a próxima linha

  if ($nivel2 > $nivel) {
   echo "[" . $material2 . "] é filho de [" . $material . "]\r\n";
  } else if ($nivel2 < $nivel) {
   echo "[" . $material2 . "] é pai [" . $material . "]\r\n";     
  } else {
   echo "[" . $material2 . "] é mesmo nivel de [" . $material . "]\r\n";
  }

  $l++; // Adianta uma linha já que li duas num laço apenas 
 } else {
  echo "[" . $material . "] não tem próxima comparação\r\n";
 }   
}
?>
```

Para corrigir esse buraco como disse eu juntaria todo mundo em grupos de niveis tipo todos nivel 1,2,3 e etc. em matrizes, e depois apenas filtraria a partir de um nivel até o nivel máximo, por exemplo se ele vai até o 5 eu poderia pedir do 3 até o 5. Ficando mais ou menos assim o código.

**Exemplo #2** *(pela minha lógica)*

```
<?php
// Abre o arquivo e trasforma cada linha uma posição de uma matriz
$materiais = file("material1.txt");

// Percore todas as linhas do arquivo (ignorando a primeira linha)
// E agrupa todo mundo nos respectivos niveis
$grupos = array();  // Variavel vazia para montar os niveis
for ($l = 1; $l < count($materiais); $l++) {
 list($material, $nivel, $quantidade, $tipo) = explode("|", $materiais[$l]); 
 $grupos[$nivel][] = array($material, $nivel, $quantidade, $tipo); 
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------
$nivel_inicio = 2; // Nivel minino a mostar (no exemplo 2)

// Inicia a filtragem atarves do nivel
$novo_grupo = array(); 
foreach ($grupos as $nivel => $valores) {
 if ($nivel_inicio <= $nivel) {
  $novo_grupo[$nivel][] = $valores;
 }
}

print_r($novo_grupo);
?>
```